# Cypress Cucumber - Error : Multiple matching step definitions for

Tags: cucumber, cypress

After upgrading Cypress to 11 the same E2E code base throws error:
Multiple matching step definitions for

There was no duplication before and after the upgrade, I tried to find the duplication
of : /^I open the foo Home Page$/ I can find only one occurence.

```
 1) Administration - General tests
       Check the sub menus of Administration:
     Error: Multiple matching step definitions for: I open the foo Home Page
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
 /^I open the foo Home Page$/
      at Registry.resolveStepDefintion (http://localhost:4433/__cypress/tests?p=src\e2e\administration\foo-administration.feature:13255:19)
      at Registry.runStepDefininition (http://localhost:4433/__cypress/tests?p=src\e2e\administration\foo-administration.feature:13270:39)
```

Can somebody help me to understand why I can get this confusing message?

Thanks in advance

Csaba

Comment: You don't have any other logs regarding the files that are considered step? And I have you updated the cucumber-cypress ?

Comment: It wasn't me who made this upgrade (mono-repo with 4 projects) but I have to fix one of the projects I'm involved in. Which is not a problem the problem is this totally misleading error, why ? How can it happen ? I did not check the logs yet, because I dont know them one by one and I dont know which one would be the best to check. There is no extra log in the code base side because the Git would noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

The step 'I open the foo Home Page' was inherited and the inheritance caused this strange bug.
As I moved this step into the child stepper class then problem is gone.
At the moment I don't know better solution, that's it.